# how do I make a custom gradient shape mask or vector mask that is gradually transparent on one side only?

Tags: vector, gradient, mask, creative-cloud

Using Vector masks or layer masks, In photoshop CC, how do I make a custom gradient shape mask or vector mask that has a gradient on one side only? A side that is curved and the gradient should follow the shape's curvature precisely .

below  is an example mask
[image]

Image Samples:
My goal is to create a composite of these 2 images
[image]

Final image should look something like this:
[image]

the green shade is where blending should be (for a natural finish)
[image]

Comment: Hi mike, what program are you using? Image sample?

Comment: Hi Danielillo. I'm using Photoshop CC

Comment: Ok, you should add it as a tag below your question and delete it from the title. I don't think you are going to get a good answer without an image sample about what do you want to get. As the question is formulated, the solution is to use the same gradient that you have put on the question as a mask.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this question. A mask that has transparency and non transparency? Pretty sure that's just a normal mask. A side that is curved and the gradient should follow the shapes curvature... What shape? - Can you elaborate a little? Maybe try to specify what kind of end result you are after? Or pinpoint exactly what part of making this mask is giving you trouble. Is it maybe that you don't know how to draw a white blurry circle on a black background?

Comment: I must use the first image as a mask. The black area of the mask will hide the image, the white area will keep the image as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your images, I would draw a closed curved path with the Pen tool, turn the path into a selection, apply some feathering, add the layer mask.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I was kinda hoping for this alternative. feathering a Vector shape / path

Answer (score 1):

You can define this adjusting the **Refine Mask Edge** options

- Background layer

[image: first layer]

- Top layer

[image: second layer]

- Top Layer Mask

[image: MASK]

- Double click on the mask to edit the **Mask Properties** and click on **Refine Mask Edge**: reduce Shift Edge, change Radius, apply Feather.

[image: Refine Edge]

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thank you ! Danielillo